# Is there a way to get the name of an ng-model from an element

Tags: angularjs

I want to find the name of the model on the active element. Basically I have document.activeElement how do I find out what it's ng-model is.

```
<input ng-model="myModel">
```

So in the above control if that was active how would I be able to find out that we are in the element with the ng-model of myModel. This is technically a workaround for adding an id or a name, but I would rather not do it if I can

As an aside this code is in the controller not a directive.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you need - 'try ng-click(this)' - and print out the value (this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9791/)
You need to get the element object as discribed in the comment in the code and then access it with `attr`

```
// get element
var result = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

// get object using jQLite or jQuery
var ele = angular.element(result);

// access 'ng-model' as 'attribute'
alert(ele.attr('ng-model'));
```

***CAUTION: Here it's shown just for example considering just one input element. Use proper class/element/attribute `selector` to get proper element you want to target.***

Comment: So for me I needed to do this: angular.element(document.activeElement).attr('ng-model'); which is basically a combination of your three lines. Thanks

Comment: yep, for the sake of understanding of the other devs I put it in three lines

Answer (score 0):

input/element In Angularjs will bind a ng-model.Without using id or classes to get the element DOM can use $('[ng-model="Model"]') But If the model is under ng-repeat.

if you write 
and to get the element use $('[ng-model="name"]'), it will inject that particular element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

With `document.activeElement`, you can access the list of attributes on the returned element like this:

```
var nameOfModel = document.activeElement.attributes['ng-model'].value;
```